# Given a known Bayesian Belief Network or Causal DAG, how can we score the value of different pieces of evidence?

Tags: bayesian, causality, bayesian-network

Assume we know the BBN (Bayesian Belief Network), how can we score the value of each additional piece of evidence that the system ingests?

In simpler terms, here are two example use cases:

Make an app to quantify a kids hot or cold guessing game?

Make an app to reward detectives after the case is solved for the value of the evidence they brought into the analysis?